# Adding Items to a string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I need a way to prepend items on to an existing string array, such that:

```
string[] dirParams = null;

if (Request.Params["locationDirection_0"] != "")
{
    dirParams = Request.Params["locationDirection_0"].Split(',');
}

if (Request.Params["locationDirection_1"] != "")
{
    dirParams = Request.Params["locationDirection_1"].Split(',');
}

if (Request.Params["locationDirection_2"] != "")
{
    dirParams = Request.Params["locationDirection_2"].Split(',');
}

if (Request.Params["locationDirection_3"] != "")
{
    dirParams = Request.Params["locationDirection_3"].Split(',');
}
```

will give me a string array of about 4 items (assuming none of the requests coming in are empty)

whats the easiest way to do this, I thought of using a list and or a dictonary, neither will work for what I want to do, string array is all I want.

Comment: Why not use a List, then convert to array?

Comment: Do you mean prepend? Or do you really mean append?

Answer (score 2):

Use a list instead:

```
        List<string> dirParams = new List<string>();

        if (Request.Params["locationDirection_0"] != "")
        {
            dirParams.AddRange(Request.Params["locationDirection_0"].Split(','));
        }

        if (Request.Params["locationDirection_1"] != "")
        {
            dirParams.AddRange(Request.Params["locationDirection_1"].Split(','));
        }

        if (Request.Params["locationDirection_2"] != "")
        {
            dirParams.AddRange(Request.Params["locationDirection_2"].Split(','));
        }

        if (Request.Params["locationDirection_3"] != "")
        {
            dirParams.AddRange(Request.Params["locationDirection_3"].Split(','));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `List<string>` and then the `ToArray()` method to convert it into a `string[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Build your items in a `List<string>` then use LINQ's `.ToArray ()` to convert it into an array.

Comment: Note that [`List.ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819.aspx) isn't a component of LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Linq?

```
var dirParam = Enumerable.Range(0, 4)
              .Select(i => Request.Params["locationDirection_" + i])
              .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
              .SelectMany(s => s.Split(','))
              .ToArray();
```